# webforms table deforms after adding text

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So i need add "*" to cells that are in biggest spot with same color etc. When i add "*" to a cell, table looks ugly, deformed: [How looks table after adding "*"*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLsRm.png)
Without adding "": [How table looks without adding any text to a cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I19ZB.png)

How i can solve this? I don't mind making bigger cells.

```
    void CreateTable(int[,] Table, Demė deme, int[,] colorTable) //Demė is spot
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Table.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < Table.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                TableCell red = new TableCell();
                red.BackColor = Color.Red;
                red.Text = " ";
                TableCell green = new TableCell();
                green.BackColor = Color.Green;
                green.Text = " ";
                TableCell yellow = new TableCell();
                yellow.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                yellow.Text = " ";
                if (colorTable[i, j] == -1)
                {
                    if (Table[i, j] == deme.ID)
                    {
                        red.Text = "*";
                    }
                    row.Cells.Add(red);
                }
                else if (colorTable[i, j] == -2)
                {
                    if (Table[i, j] == deme.ID)
                    {
                        green.Text = "*";
                    }
                    row.Cells.Add(green);
                }
                else if (colorTable[i, j] == -3)
                {
                    if (Table[i, j] == deme.ID)
                    {
                        yellow.Text = "*";
                    }
                    row.Cells.Add(yellow);
                }
            }

            Table1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ASP.NET Web Application (.Net Framework), webforms

Comment: You've changed the cell content from nothing to `"*"`.  Try setting the empty cells to `"&nbsp;"`

Comment: @Simas Please add tags for the relevant technologies, rather than adding them to the title.

Comment: Please post your rendered html (just the relevant part) and css (just the relevant part). You need to adjust your styles and / or the content in the table cells

Comment: @Jonathan <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="15" CellSpacing="12" GridLines="Both" Font-Size="Medium">
            </asp:Table>